# getting the values in one column corresponding to values in anothe column AFTER groupby

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe as below

```html
Cycle Type Time Switch
7 2 121 -0.027
7 2 146 0.021
7 2 211 -0.126
7 2 314 0.055
7 2 115 -0.023
7 2 414 0.004
5 2 216 0.003
5 2 286 -0.145
5 2 291 0.007
5 2 301 -0.001
5 2 316 0.02
5 2 371 -0.195
5 2 376 0.015
7 6 381 -0.001
7 6 386 0.016
7 6 421 -0.241
7 6 436 0.055
7 6 446 -0.023
7 6 451 0.004
```

I have to groupby 'Cycle' & Type'. Then get the 'Time' corresponding to highest, 2nd highest, 3rd highest values of 'Switch'

So the output would be 314 (because max of Switch is 0.55), 146 (because the 2nd highest of Switch is 0.21) and 414(because the 3rd highest of Switch is 0.0.004) in the group 1&2 (like this i need the values for all the groups).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [`nlargest()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.nlargest.html) with `groupby` the drop level_0 and level_1

if you want to increase nlargest you can change 3 in nlargest to get any maxium values you want

```
res= df.groupby(['Cycle','Type'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3, 'Switch'))
res.reset_index(inplace=True)
res.drop(['level_0','level_1'],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

## Addition to your question

you should add desired output to your question
What I have understand from your comment

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data={"Cycle":[7,7,7,7,5,5,5,5],
                     "Type":[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
                     "time":[13,1231,122,11,105,106,12,18],
                     "Switch":[-0.333,1.2,0.5,125,12.2,22.2,0.3,12]})
res= df.groupby(['Cycle','Type'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.nlargest(3, 'Switch'))
res.reset_index(inplace=True)

res.drop(['level_0','level_1'],axis=1,inplace=True)

res['col_name'] = 'time'+ res.groupby(['Cycle'],as_index=False).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)

final_res = pd.pivot_table(res,index=['Cycle','Type'],columns='col_name',values='time').reset_index()
final_res.columns.name = ''
print(final_res)
```

```
  Cycle Type    time1   time2   time3
0   5   2        106    105     18
1   7   2         11    1231    122
```

Comment: your code works. But i am trying to get these 3 times into another df which has one line for each cycle. So, these three need to be added to that dataframe as 3 columns (may be something like time1,time2& time3)

Comment: you should update your question with proper desired outcome

Comment: @mohanys what I have understand from your question I have updated the answer kindly review it

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I thought that I would be able to add the values into the other df if I just got these values. However,I could not. Now, with the new code, I could do it with a bit of tweak. The df to which i have to add these values already exists. Hence I had to add the below 2 lines after your code & it worked perfectly. Thanks for the guidance. `final_res.set_index(['Cycle','Type'],inplace=True)
grouped_data = grouped_data.join(final_res , on=['Cycle','Type'])`